# different versions of empty delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, is-empty

Is there any technical difference between

```
Action foo = null;
```

and

```
Action foo = delegate { };
```

and

```
Action foo = () => {};
```

?

Semantically, they all represent an empty delegate, but I would like to know if there is more going on under the hood.

The reason why I'm asking is that I need to initialize a delegate so that I can later add methods to its invocation list. This does not work if it is not initialized:

```
Action foo;
...
foo += () => { Console.WriteLine("Hello world!"); };
// compiler error CS0165: use of unassigned local variable
```

But I want to initialize my `Action` so that it takes as little memory and execution time as possible. So if there actually IS a difference, which one will save more space/time?

Bonus question: Are there any other elementary ways of defining a semantically empty delegate, and if yes, will there be yet other things going on under the hood?

Comment: Have you tried building your app and decompiling the result using ILSpy to compare?

Comment: They compile to the same thing. `Action foo = delegate { }` is C# 2 and is kind of deprecated. That syntax was replaced in C# 3 when they introduced lambda's

Comment: They are not the same.  The 2nd and 3rd syntax don't create an "empty" delegate.  It is common hack to avoid having to check for null when you raise an event.  Not exactly the C# way, but if the perf is not critical then it doesn't matter.

Comment: The null check can easily incorporated into the method call: `foo?.Invoke()`. Therefore, I don't see the need to avoid it - except if the null check that is done internally takes more time than invoking an empty method. It is part of my question if this is the case.